# Hover on layer A, tooltip from Layer B

Tags: javascript, leaflet, tooltip, mouseover, layer

I've got two layers with houses. One has housing groups (MultiPolygon), which has a mouseover (hover function) to show which houses belong together. The other layer contains single houses. On mouseover, a tooltip should show its address.

It think, the problem is that both layers to be topmost? Is there a work-around?

Comment: Please post some of your code relating to the issue. 

As far as I can tell, you've got two stacked elements and when you hover over the top element you get the ToolTip showing up from the bottom element? Is this correct?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to answer your question and help you fix potential mistakes you've made you will need to show some Code you have tried and share the research you've made with us. Here are instructions on how to create a **Minimal, Complete, Verifyable Example**: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to post the links: Tooltip works: https://jsfiddle.net/48n4sk4q/2/
Hover works: https://jsfiddle.net/48n4sk4q/3/
Combination doesn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/48n4sk4q/3/

Comment: Pardon, the last link should be http://jsfiddle.net/48n4sk4q/1